# Can JobKey be changed? How?

Tags: c#, quartz.net, job-scheduling

What are the dangers of changing a `JobKey` without tampering with its schedule? And how can we do it? I suppose we should change the associated triggers with it as well, right?

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @CircularReference I am running campaigns. Campaign information is stored in the database and my job keys are the names of my campaigns,too. I'd like the user to be able to rename a campaign. If a campaign is renamed, its `JobKey` will stay the old one. Even though I have campaign's `Id` stored in `JobDataMap` already but I will have incompatibility with the updated name of my campaign. / I haven't tried it so far. And if it's dangerous I will prevent the user from renaming the campaign name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a different job so you would have to:

- Retrieve the job with the old `JobKey` and call `scheduler.DeleteJob(key)` since you want both the `JobDetail` and `Trigger` removed.
- Reschedule with your new `JobKey` and the old schedule.

However, since a campaign has an Id you can use that as a `JobKey`, the assumption here being that an Id will not change. If it's important for users to identify jobs by their campaign name, you can build a new `JobDetail` with similar parameters as the existing one, but change the `Description` to match the new campaign name and then call:

```
 scheduler.AddJob(jobDetail, true)
```

which should replace the old `JobDetail` with the new one.

Comment: It sounds a bit risky for now. I will stick to keeping my campaign names. But your answer is correct and as always you are great help in my development with Quartz.Net.